# How do I resolve this error "verifier detected internal inconsistency or security prolbem" while remotely debugging a JVM in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, intellij-idea-2018

How do I resolve this error in IntelliJ IDEA 2018 while remotely debugging a JVM running inside docker inside a ubuntu VM.

```
Hot Swap failed.
host port: verifier detected internal inconsistency or security problem
host port: Verification error: verifier detected internal inconsistency or security problem
```

I am using:

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3 EAP (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-181.4892.5 built on April 26, 2018

The JRE in docker container is:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

[image]
[image]